# How can I read data that meet or satisfy a particular condition from xml

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

**If I have this data model class:**

```
public class Person
{
    private int _id;
    private int _deptID;
    private string _firstName;
    private string _lastName;

    public int ID
    {
        get { return _deptID; }
        set { _deptID = value; }
    }

    public int DeptID
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set { _firstName = value; }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set { _lastName = value; }
    }
```

**... and then create my data set**

```
    private List<Person> GeneratePersonData()
    {
        List<Person> personData = new List<Person>();
      personData.Add(new Person() { ID = 1, DeptID = 25, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" });
        personData.Add(new Person() { ID = 2, DeptID = 25, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" });
        personData.Add(new Person() { ID = 3, DeptID = 105, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" });
        personData.Add(new Person() { ID = 4, DeptID = 43, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" });
        personData.Add(new Person() { ID = 5, DeptID = 25, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" });
        personData.Add(new Person() { ID = 6, DeptID = 32, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" });
        personData.Add(new Person() { ID = 7, DeptID = 2, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" });
        personData.Add(new Person() { ID = 8, DeptID = 25, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" });
        personData.Add(new Person() { ID = 9, DeptID = 2, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" });

        return personData;
    }
```

**And then I store my data into xml like this:**

```
    private void StorePersonData()
    { 
    XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        xmlWriterSettings.Indent = true;

        using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("Person.xml", FileMode.Create))
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Person>));
                using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream, xmlWriterSettings))
                {
                    serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, GeneratePersonData());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Now, what I want to do is read only the persons with a particular deptID from the xml into a new list so I do this:**

```
    private void ReadPersonData(int deptID)
    {
        List<Person>data = new List<Person>();
        List<Person> newData = new List<Person>();

        using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("Person.xml", FileMode.Open))
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Person>));
                 data = (List<Person>)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
        {
            if (data[i]._deptID == deptID)
            {
                newData.Add(data[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this method is ridiculously slow if I have a really large data set. Is there a way in xml to read only data that satisfy a certain condition?

Answer (score 0):

No - once you had taken an approach of saving data in XML and then querying it, it has to be slow with large data set.

is this static data or it changes ? If its a static data, why not keep the xml in memory ?

Note 1: Instead of XML, why not serialize in JSON object. the size would be much smaller and hence you would see some improvement.

Note 2 : Saving Data in JSON and XML is good when you are talking with different application(say one built in .net and one built in java). With these open formats you can easily pass data. What I see is, its you storing the data and its you reading the data ? Why XML (or JSON) ??

**UPDATE**

For JSON serialization - you could use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx

if this xml never changes then do not read it every time. Read and parse the xml, keep it in memomry, what every way you like (session, static variable, cache).

Why are you not using DB for storing the same information ? One application can write the data in DB and other application would retrieve the data from DB ?

Comment: its static data. How do you keep xml in memory and why do that? **Note 1:** I'll look into JSON serialization, I do not know how to do that. **Note 2:** I am talking with different app platforms. But if not xml (or JSON), then what do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to reconsider using XML to store your data. There isn't much structure in your data, and you're doing random access. It really seems like a database would do a better job of storing, indexing, and retrieving/filtering this data; then you can export the result sets to XML as needed.